# Can't enable "Developer options" on Redmi devices

Tags: developer-options, redmi

The [official guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) says:

> On Android 4.1 and lower, the Developer options screen is available by default. On Android 4.2 and higher, you must enable this screen as follows:
>
> 1. Open the Settings app.
> 2. (Only on Android 8.0 or higher) Select System.
> 3. Scroll to the bottom and select About phone.
> 4. Scroll to the bottom and tap Build number 7 times.
> 5. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options near the bottom.

I'm using Android 8.1 and there's no "System" option, but there's "About phone" right on the first Settings screen. However, inside "About phone", there's no "Build number". My phone is a Redmi 6, did they change the Android interface, or Android 8.1 interface is different, or what?

[image: Screenshot 1]]

[image: Screenshot 2]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a big secret that the Xiaomi uses MIUI which is a heavily modified Android OS.

Just searching the net quickly gets you the result that on MIUI you have to tap the field `MIUI Version` 7 times.

Anyway you could have found out that yourself by just tapping all available fields 7 times...

Comment: MIUI is just one of the many different words around here. And yes, if this site didn't exist we all could try every possibility, every time a problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too:

Settings->About phone->Software info->Build number. Now tap it 7 times, then you will be in developer mode. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, is this answer about the Redmi/Xiaomi device? Since some brands customize their own Android, some settings are located differently based on their device models and Android version, so it'd be great to mention the device model and Android version. Thanks.